# compare a measure to a value in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

Power BI noob here, still thinking like a SQL coder, so please be patient.

How can I use the user name of the person running the report to filter the report?

As a convenience for my users, I want to provide a way for them to automatically filter to only see data related to their office or region.  I have a Person table that includes details like their office location.  If I can filter that based on the user name of the person running the report, and join it to the rest of the data, that would work.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to get the user name in M.

Using the `USERNAME()` function in DAX, I don't see a way to compare this with individual values in a column.  I get an error about being unable to compare a measure to multiple values.

It seems this would be a common request, so I'm sure somebody has solved this problem.  But I haven't yet found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RLS in your model. You can use function USERNAME(),USEROBJECTID (), USERPRINCIPALNAME (); The last one is useful if you have table with users and their email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

check also this GuyInCube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxU_FYSSnYU

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware of the [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#using-the-username-or-userprincipalname-dax-function) between `USERNAME()` and `USERPRINCIPALNAME()`. Most likely you will want to use the later one.

You can't use neither of these in M. Imagine your model is importing the data. The M code is executed once in the context of one user, then each other user accessing the published report will reuse the already loaded and calculated model. And of course, these are DAX functions, not M.

So in DAX you can use these to compare their values to columns from your model. You didn't gave any information about your model, but lets say there is a table `Sales` with columns `Customer` and `Amount`:

| Customer | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Bill Gates@Microsoft.local | 100 |
| Steve Ballmer@Microsoft.local | 110 |

In this case, you can write a measure like this:

```
My Sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales'[Amount]), 'Sales'[Client] = USERPRINCIPALNAME())
```

When Bill Gates opens the report, he will see sales amount of 100, while if Steve Ballmer opens it he will see 110.

For diagnostic purpose, you can make a measure like this and show it somewhere in your report:

```
Who am I = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

If your goal is to build dynamic Row-Level Security within Power BI, it has some functionality which might help you, so take a look at these articles:

- [Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls)
- [Restrict data access with row-level security (RLS) for Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-rls)
- [Row-level security (RLS) guidance in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/rls-guidance)
- [Dynamic Row Level Security with Profiles and Users in Power BI : Many-to-Many Relationship](https://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-profiles-and-users-in-power-bi)